# Rails-i18n would'nt load translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, rubygems, translation

I've added the gem "rails-i18n" but when I try to get the transaltion of "date.order". All fails, but when I write the translation in my own file app, it works ?

**Update 10/31/2012**
My gem file is :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "mysql2", ">= 0.3.11"
gem "haml", ">= 3.1.7"
gem "haml-rails", ">= 0.3.5", :group => :development
gem "hpricot", ">= 0.8.6", :group => :development
gem "ruby_parser", ">= 2.3.1", :group => :development
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.11.4", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "capybara", ">= 1.1.2", :group => :test
gem "email_spec", ">= 1.2.1", :group => :test
gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 4.1.0", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "bootstrap-sass", ">= 2.1.0.1"
gem "devise", ">= 2.1.2"
gem "cancan", ">= 1.6.8"
gem "rolify", ">= 3.2.0"
gem "simple_form", ">= 2.0.4"
gem "quiet_assets", ">= 1.0.1", :group => :development
gem "therubyracer", ">= 0.10.2", :group => :assets, :platform => :ruby
gem 'i18n'
gem 'rails-i18n'
```

And my error is in a view : https://gist.github.com/3990266

Comment: Also, you need to include what version of Rails you're using. The rails-i18n gem is a default gem that's already included with rails. You shouldn't normally have to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that you must never write

```
en:
  date: Date
```

In your own translation and will cause many bugs ...